# Função Sleep ou Wait travando planilha no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, planilha

Estou programando uma macro em vba, que faz a conexão com um banco de dados sql server e faz um select em uma tabela e me retorna a hora da ultima alteração no banco. Eu criei um programa em vba que pega a hora do sistema e faz um calculo para mostrar diferença, o problema é que o loop deve roda a cada 5 min.

Eu utilizei a função `Sleep`. Porém ela trava a planilha durante os min colocados dentro do `Sleep`.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de não travar a planilha utilizando outra função, ou pega essa linha de código `Plan1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset`  e atribuir uma varivel.

OBS:Já usei a função `Sleep` e a mesma trava o programa

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Function conexao()

   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   Dim sql As String
   Dim hora As Date
   Dim hora_banco As String
   Dim total As Integer
   Dim s As String
   Dim hora_Inicial As Date
   Dim Hora_final As Date
   Dim strConn As String

   'Atribui horas inicias e finais para as variaveis

   hora_Inicial = TimeValue("8:00:00")
   Hora_final = TimeValue("18:00:00")
   'Pega a hora do sistema

   hora = TimeValue(Time())

       ' faz a conexao com o banco
      strConn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=d1736368;Database=DB_CONSIGNADO_ESPECIFICO"
    'abre a conexao
       cn.Open strConn
       'Cria o objeto Recordset
        Dim rs, a As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        Set a = New ADODB.Recordset
         'pega a hora do sistema
        hora = Time()


   Do Until hora_Inicial >= Hora_final
   DoEvents

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
        'faz o select no banco de dados e converte para hora
        sql = "SELECT top 1 Convert(Char(8),GetDate(),114),(DT_SISTEMA) FROM T_PROPOSTA_FILHOTE"
        'printa o valor das variaveis
        Debug.Print hora
        Debug.Print sql

       'inicia o bloco with com a varivale rs
       With rs
           .ActiveConnection = cn
           .Open sql
            Plan1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
           .Close
       End With
   'recebe o ultima atualizacao de hora do banco
       hora_banco = CDate(Range("A2").Value)
       total = hora - (hora_banco = CDate(Range("A2").Value))
       Debug.Print total

       If total >= 5 Then

           s = Shell("C:\teste\Reinicia_Robo.bat", vbNormalFocus)

       End If

       DoEvents

       Loop
       'fecha a conexao
       cn.Close
       Set rs = Nothing
       Set cn = Nothing

   End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solução

A função `Wait` suspende o processamento do Excel.

Então a alternativa do código a seguir deve ser utilizada para parar somente o código e não a Planilha Excel.

```
TempoEspera = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10")
While Now() < TempoEspera
    DoEvents
Wend
```

#### Observação

E para declarar a função `Sleep`, faça da seguinte maneira para evitar erros:

```
#If VBA7 Then  
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) '64 Bit  
#Else  
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long) '32 Bit  
#End If
```

Comment: Então já tentei utilizar o sleep e travou do mesmo jeito, a questão é teria alguma forma só executar o código e não precisar da planilha?sou bem iniciante em vba

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta, mas você utiliza o primeiro código no lugar de `Wait()`

Comment: sim, já tinha utilizado antes o Sleep coloquei 1 min de espera,o problema é que toda vez que ele dá esse 1 min de atraso ele trava o excel, eu gostaria de saber se teria alguma forma de dá uma pausa na execução do código, sem travar o excel para que eu possa usa-lo normalmente,se vc conhecer uma outra alternativa,pode ser em vba no access, ou até mesmo visual basic.

Comment: Sim, o primeiro código da resposta pausa o código pelo tempo determinado. Utilizando um loop while e não trava o Excel.

Comment: cara muito obrigado,consegui aqui,então eu só precisava fazer o select em um determinado tempo para ele fazer a verificação,coloquei aquele primeiro código que vc me passou ,dentro do meu loop principal que faz o select e conseguir programar ele para fazer o select a cada 1 min por exemplo,nem precisava do Sleep.